# MobilePush Android SDK(8.0.8) not receiving Push Messages

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, notification, mobilepush-android, push-notification

I have integrated Mobile Push SDK (8.0.8) in my Android App. It is not able to receive push messages sent from Marketing Cloud Mobile Push. I am initializing the SDK in the onCreate of my Applicatinon class and have no other Push Provider integrated in the app. I followed the guidelines to troubleshoot [push setup](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html)

The application is able to receive push directly from FCM by performing this test:

```
export FCM_SERVER_KEY=#Use value from Firebase console
curl --header "Authorization: key=$FCM_SERVER_KEY" \
  --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
  -d "{\"to\":\"$PUSH_TOKEN\",\"data\":{\"_m\":\"test_message\",\"alert\":\"It Worked!\",\"title\":\"Test Push\", \"_sid\":\"SFMC\"}}"
```

After that it says to wait for 5 minutes and then test for push, but I am not able to receive any Push Message at all.

I am using this rest API to send Push Messages- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postMessageAppSend.html?q=message%20app

Here are the logs from SDK-

```
MarketingCloudSdk           V  Marketing Cloud initialization successful.
MarketingCloudSdk           I  initConfig: MarketingCloudConfig(applicationId=xxxxx, accessToken=xxxx, senderId=xxxxx, marketingCloudServerUrl=https://xxxx.device.marketingcloudapis.com, mid=xxxxxx, analyticsEnabled=true, geofencingEnabled=false, inboxEnabled=true, piAnalyticsEnabled=false, proximityEnabled=false, markMessageReadOnInboxNotificationOpen=true, delayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet=false, useLegacyPiIdentifier=true, notificationCustomizationOptions={smallIconResId=2131165301, launchIntentProvider=Application$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0, channelIdProvider=null}, proximityNotificationCustomizationOptions=null, urlHandler=Application@1a1d335, appPackageName=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx, appVersionName=1.0.0, predictiveIntelligenceServerUrl=https://xxxxx.json)
MarketingCloudSdk           I  initStatus: InitializationStatus(status=SUCCESS, unrecoverableException=null, locationsError=false, playServicesStatus=-1, playServicesMessage=null, encryptionChanged=false, storageError=false, proximityError=false, messagingPermissionError=false, sslProviderEnablementError=false, initializedComponents=[BehaviorManager, LifecycleManager, RequestManager, AlarmScheduler, SyncRoute, ControlChannel, ConfigComponent, LocationManager, ProximityManager, AnalyticsManager, InboxMessageManager, NotificationManager, RegionMessageManager, PushMessageManager, RegistrationManager, InAppMessageManager, Event], isUsable=true)
MarketingCloudSdk           I  RegistrationManager: 
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                      "current_registration": {
                                                                                                        "deviceID": "xxxxxx",
                                                                                                        "sdk_Version": "8.0.8",
                                                                                                        "app_Version": "1.0.0 : 1",
                                                                                                        "dST": false,
                                                                                                        "location_Enabled": false,
                                                                                                        "proximity_Enabled": false,
                                                                                                        "platform_Version": "10",
                                                                                                        "push_Enabled": true,
                                                                                                        "timeZone": "19800",
                                                                                                        "platform": "Android",
                                                                                                        "hwid": "samsung SM-M305F",
                                                                                                        "etAppId": "xxxxxx",
                                                                                                        "locale": "en_GB",
                                                                                                        "tags": [
                                                                                                          "ALL",
                                                                                                          "Android",
                                                                                                          "DEBUG"
                                                                                                        ],
                                                                                                        "attributes": []
                                                                                                      }
                                                                                                    }
MarketingCloudSdk           I  PushMessageManager: 
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                      "pushEnabled": true,
                                                                                                      "pushPermissionsAllowed": true,
                                                                                                      "debugInfo": {
                                                                                                        "senderId": "xxxxxx",
                                                                                                        "deviceToken": null,
                                                                                                        "firebaseApps": [
                                                                                                          "FirebaseApp{name=[DEFAULT], options=FirebaseOptions{applicationId=xxxxx, apiKey=xxxxxxx, databaseUrl=null, gcmSenderId=xxxxxxx, storageBucket=xxxx-xxxx.appspot.com, projectId=xxxx-xxxxx}}"
                                                                                                        ],
                                                                                                        "c2dmReceiver": [
                                                                                                          {
                                                                                                            "name": "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver",
                                                                                                            "priority": 0
                                                                                                          }
                                                                                                        ],
                                                                                                        "instanceIdService": [],
                                                                                                        "messagingService": [
                                                                                                          {
                                                                                                            "name": "com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.MCFirebaseMessagingService",
                                                                                                            "priority": -1
                                                                                                          },
                                                                                                          {
                                                                                                            "name": "com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService",
                                                                                                            "priority": -500
                                                                                                          }
                                                                                                        ]
                                                                                                      }
                                                                                                    }
MarketingCloudSdk           I  InApp Events: {
                                                                                                      "triggers": []
                                                                                                    }
~!MarketingCloudSdk         V  Control Channel blocked value 0 received
MarketingCloudSdk           I  Registration: Registration(id=0, signedString=null, deviceId=415632e7-a97d-4cc5-b15f-f57c05844f88, systemToken=e5HL2Pr1S2-M5euaSc__ew:APA91bFLcQs2TVWYRINBLvaLZJrHTewFZXNtvRkI8lqca2Swz6oZb_ISQqQHwXhvGMeqrhxXz24v7RQp3TLtp_UZ-TOi8N10m_jVtNV1pXe3BYLaoavWzEkGkPjGxjNxp8EXoSOFW5rH, sdkVersion=8.0.8, appVersion=1.0.0 : 1, dst=false, locationEnabled=false, proximityEnabled=false, platformVersion=10, pushEnabled=true, timeZone=19800, contactKey=null, platform=Android, hwid=samsung SM-M305F, appId=xxxxxxxx, locale=en_GB, tags=[ALL, Android, DEBUG], attributes={})
MarketingCloudSdk           I  TOKEN: e5HL2Pr1S2-M5euaSc__ew:APA91bFLcQs2TVWYRINBLvaLZJrHTewFZXNtvRkI8lqca2Swz6oZb_ISQqQHwXhvGMeqrhxXz24v7RQp3TLtp_UZ-TOi8N10m_jVtNV1pXe3BYLaoavWzEkGkPjGxjNxp8EXoSOFW5rH
~!MarketingCloudSdk         V  Control Channel blocked value 0 received
```

I am still confused what I am doing wrong here, any help in this regard would be appreciated.

P.S. - Preserving keys with 'xxxxx...'

Comment: This appears to be a simple timing issue as the registration you originally transmitted did not yet have a push token. Those are fetched asynchronously via Firebase's APIs and I see later that you have a registration with a token. Review your logs for the registration transmission and the subsequent 201 success message. From that point you should be able to target the device in about 2 min.

Comment: If not, open a support case.

Comment: @BillMote I did wait for more than 5 min, but still I was not able to receive any push messages. I cannot open a support case, since I am not the owner of the Mobile Push Application (Enterprise Project).

Comment: Also @BillMote could you please help me understand, why this message is being logged - Control Channel blocked value 0 received

Comment: You're never going to solve this without a support ticket. If you have followed the instructions then this should work perfectly. We have thousands of customers with billions (yes, with a B) of installations. The log is for debugging.

Comment: The simplest troubleshooting steps are these ... 1) is it registered? 2) is it opted-in? 3) is the device in the audience list? 4) was the send successful? 5) what did the feedback service say? Since you can push directly to the device and you've shown a registration we know the answer to #1 is yes, but as you never show a token being sent, we have to assume #2 is no. Work your way through the steps verifying each one.

Comment: Thanks @BillMote for the troubleshooting steps. Appreciated.

Comment: Did this get resolved?

Comment: nope, not yet. It was backlogged, but active development on slated to start again. @BillMote